# Haskell beginner question, set up pairs in definition

Tags: list, haskell, combinations, cartesian-product

So I'm really new to Haskell and have a definition called:

```
 x :: [(char,Int)]
```

`x` needs to get defined as a function that just puts the chars `(x,y,z)` together with `(1,2,3)` in every way.

So when I call `x` I just want to get the output of `[x,1], [x,2], [x,3], [y,1], [y,2]` and so on.

Might be some easy problem but I'm confused that there is no actual input in the `x` function. It just needs to output the lists.

I have tried creating both lists (the number and char list) but how do I put them together in the function ?

Comment: hint: use list comprehension ;) If you fail, edit thias question with your doubts

Comment: ok ive got it , thanks for the tip :D

Comment: Think about your function x. You say it has no inputs, but where does it get the tuples (or lists?) that you want combined? Note that you can't use parentheses and square brackets interchangeably here, so I'm not 100% sure of exactly what you are looking for. Perhaps a function that takes two LISTS and produces one LIST of pairs (i.e. a list of 2-tuples)? I assume that you don't want to use exactly and only the characters x,y,z and 1,2,3 but something more flexible (e.g. any two lists of equal size?).

Comment: `x :: [(Char, Int)]` is not a definition; it's a type annotation. Also, `x` is not a function, but a list of tuples. A function that that takes a list of characters `[Char]` and a list of integers `[Int]` to produce something with the same type of `x` would have the type `[Char] -> [Int] -> [(Char, Int)]`. Your job is to define some function `foo :: [Char] -> [Int] -> [(Char, Int)]`.

Comment: @Willem corrections go to answers, not questions. :) I think your edit should be rolled back.

Answer (score 2):

`x` is not a function; it's a list of tuples. You can define it directly, or you can define a function of type `foo :: [Char] -> [Int] -> [(Char, Int)]`, then set `x` by calling `foo` with two appropriate lists.

```
foo :: [Char] -> [Int] -> [(Char, Int)]
foo chars ints = ...  -- You define this

x :: [(Char, Int)]
x = foo ['x', 'y', 'z'] [1, 2, 3]
```

As for how you define `foo`, I suggest you start by reading about [list comprehensions](https://wiki.haskell.org/List_comprehension). They are not the only way to define `foo`, but they are probably the simplest. If you are familiar with list comprehensions in a language like Python, you shouldn't have a problem; Haskell is where Python got the idea.